# When to use Named HttpClient and Basic HttpClient in An IHttpClientFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

Can anyone explain the Difference between Named HttpClient and Basic HttpClient in An IHttpClientFactory and when to use Named HttpClient and Basic HttpClient

Comment: The docs here will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#consumption-patterns

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you would want to use a named client to identify a client that has a specific set of configurations. Typed clients are also named but the framework works out the name based on the type asking for a client in the ctor.

The basic client situation is one to use when you want a client that doesn't have any prescribed configuration ahead of time.